# Detecting tab using 51Degrees.mobi Foundation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, 51degrees

I am trying out to detect the Ipad or Samsung Galaxy Tab or any other Tab using 51Degrees.mobi Foundation library.

I am using Request.Browser["is_tablet"] but it is returning me false. Is there any one who knows if this is the known issue or I am making some mistake.

I am testing this using Opera Mobile Emulator

---

can you give me URL to download the simulator for iPad?

I am describing again my issue below--

I am using 51Degrees.mobi Foundation in my MVC application. When I use Request.Browser["is_tablet"] in my View Engine to check if request is from tab, its giving me false as a result. This is happening for Samsung Galaxy Tab(Opera Mobile Emulator) and Ipad (AIRiPad emulator).

In this case the Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice and Request.Browser["is_wireless_device"] is also returning false. Hence the regular MVC views designed for desktop is getting loaded. 
I am not using Locations in config file as I need to redirect to appropriate views from my view engine when request is from mobile or tablet.

Let me know is there any knows issue with is_tablet or Am I doing it wrong way or is there issue with emulator?

Comment: Have you tried with `<location>` http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Documentation/Foundation/UserGuide.aspx#LocationsCollection

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the open source lite device data, then you won't be able to detect the tablet capability. You can however detect both whether the device is mobile (IsMobile (boolean)) and the screen size (ScreenPixelsHeight (int) and ScreenPixelsWidth (int)). You may be able to determine whether or not the device is a tablet by using a combination of these values.

You can check the avaliable properties using the property dictionary [here.](http://51degrees.mobi/Products/DeviceData/PropertyDictionary.aspx?CATReferrer=1765) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Request.Browser["is_tablet"] works fine for me:

used the iPad simulator from Blackbaud labs.
http://labs.blackbaud.com/NetCommunity/article?artid=662

User-Agent:

Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10

Check your logfile App_Data/Log.txt for this entry:

*Info - Loaded 14691 devices using 12720 strings in 2295ms*

set the log level to debug in your config file
< log logFile="~/App_Data/Log.txt" logLevel="Debug"/>